# Error with importing requests module on VSCode for Python

Tags: python, import, module, python-requests, python-module

[I get this output when I try to pip install requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH68z.png)

I want to install requests and am unsure how to solve this problem. I have attempted many options to fix this problem and none have worked. I am unsure if this reflects an error in the pip command or the requests module itself. I get this error when I do it in the command prompt and vscode. The outputs also repeat when I run the command pip3 install requests as well.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).